# Which method for comparing folders is more accurate, diff -r or md5?

Tags: command-line, macos

I need to compare a couple of folders to see if they copied correctly. The `diff -r dir1 dir2` option seems the first obvious choice, but some comparisons that passed this way, didn't pass the test using the `md5` tool. Why is that? Does that mean md5 is always the better option? And could there be an even better one?

Comment: What exact commands are you running? Have you looked at any of the files that passed diff but not md5? They should be functionally identical, the only thing I can think of is there being some special character set that diff doesn't handle right, but I haven't been able to replicate this at all.

Comment: On the diff side I'm using 'diff -r dir1 dir2', while for the md5 check I individually execute 'find dir -type f -name "*" -exec md5 {} + | awk '{print $1}' | md5', replacing dir with dir1 and dir2. The contents of the directories are binary, but not the kind I can easily execute.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, unfortunately I can't replicate this different results behavior on anything on my computer. My only guess is still some special character messing up diff (since it acts more on contents, whereas md5 just makes a hash out of bytes). I know diff has an option to ignore whitespace differences, which would cause this behavior, but you're not using that option and that wouldn't make sense for a binary. :\

Comment: I've just found another difference and I'm not sure which command to trust. I used a slightly different md5 check. So first I tried this on both directories (path/to/dir1 and path/to/dir2): `find path/to/dir -type f -name "*" | md5`. That resulted in two different hashes. When I tried the diff command then with `diff -r path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2` diff doesn't report any differences.

Comment: I'm kind of grasping at straws here - do you have any symlinks in these folders? The md5 command you are running would ignore symlinks (they are not considered of type 'f') but diff would see them and throw a difference if they pointed to different folders, i.e. if your backup copy pointed to the same file in a copy on a different drive.    

Unfortunately this is the opposite of what you are seeing (here diff reports differences and md5 does not). But it's the only difference I've been able to find. Without a working example of the problem on my end, I'm kind of out of ideas.

Comment: Actually well spotted because the first occurrence where I noticed the discrepancy did have a symlink, but the second occurrence (the one I wrote about yesterday) did not. So a bit back to square one.